# WCF service reference does not include commens from original service methods

Tags: wcf, comments, intellisense

I have created a simple WCF web service with a method. This method has comments on it.

Why does the comment not appear in the service reference for a consuming app?

Is there some other way to propagate to method comments to the proxy?

```
/// <summary>
/// Do some work 
/// </summary>
public void DoWork()
{
}
```

Comment: Simple answer 2 years later, there is not a way.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear on the service reference because the comments aren't part of the service metadata. There are two options you can use to have the comments appear on the proxy:

- Share the contract interface between the server and the client (i.e., not generate the proxy, but simply reuse your interface on the client side).
- Use some custom WSDL export extension which is aware of the comments (or other attributes), and a custom WSDL import extension which can understand those when generating the client. The sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717040.aspx is one possible implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [WCF Extras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) would work for you. It sounds like what you want.

"Adding WSDL Documentation from Source Code XML Comments"

Comment: But does documentation in the WSDL become comments in the proxy code?

Comment: doesnt appear to :( But it does put them into the wsdl nicley

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your service reference is marked as internal instead of public and the warning will go away.